# UNIQID alternative

Tags: php

I'm looking to generate a UNIQUE random code.

When you use uniqid(), result is based on time, example:
if user created ID yesterday at 12:12:35 and another user create a new ID today at same time, ID are identical because based on 24 hour loop time.

I'm tinking about using microtime in this way

```
// create random based on unix epoch
$random = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
```

In this way can I grant uniqueless of generated IDs?

Comment: Can you provide an authoritative source for your claim regarding `uniqid()` generating the same string 24 hours apart?

Comment: " if user created ID yesterday at 12:12:35 and another user create a new ID today at same time, ID are identical because based on 24 hour loop time." NOOOOO its time and DATE, days changed

Comment: If you need uniqueness *and* unguessability, then don't base your id on the date/time. See [ramsey/uuid](https://github.com/ramsey/uuid).

Comment: _based on time_ where time is a timestamp identifying the year, month, day, hour, minute, second and microsecond.  So, no there will not be a collision unless you change time or date backwards on server.

Comment: @esquev, uniqID create same codes on my server...

Comment: The result of uniqid() is not based on time but timestamp, so it is not just time but date+time. And you can increase uniqueness by setting the 2nd argument (more_entropy) to true. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: please, run this on you server and see duplicated,

Comment: for($i=0;$i<20;$i++) {
    echo uniqid();
    echo '<br>';
}

Comment: ran you test code, no duplicates, if your server was very fast its possible the 2 calls were made in the same microsecond. This not at all what you said in your post, regarding be identical a **day** apart.

Answer (score 0):

The result of uniqid() is not based on time but timestamp, so it is not just time but date+time.

From [php.net uniqid page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

> Returns timestamp based unique identifier as a string.

You can set the 2nd argument 'more_entropy' to true to increase it's uniqueness.